# RcppEigen: Fastest way to square a positive definite matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, rcpp

Suppose I have a positive definite matrix `S`. I would like to compute `S %*% S` using RcppEigen. I could do:

```
using Eigen::Map;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
const Map<MatrixXd> S(as<Map<MatrixXd> >(AA));
const MatrixXd SS(S * S);
return wrap(SS);
```

But this seems wasteful, given that `S` is positive definite (though it does improve upon R's computation time by a factor of about 5). How can I use the symmetry to my advantage to reduce computation time? I've tried:

```
using Eigen::Map;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
const Map<MatrixXd> S(as<Map<MatrixXd> >(AA));
const MatrixXd SS(S.selfAdjointView<Lower>() * S.selfAdjointView<Lower>());
return wrap(SS);
```

But that does not improve computation time over the simple multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your code for utilizing symmetry doesn't work.  Secondly, their actually is an example of this in the [RcppEigen Intro](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppEigen/vignettes/RcppEigen-Introduction.pdf).

```
sqCpp <- "
using Eigen::Map;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
const Map<MatrixXd> S(as<Map<MatrixXd> >(AA));
const MatrixXd SS(S * S);
return wrap(SS);
"

triCpp <- "
using Eigen::Map;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::Lower;
const Map<MatrixXd> S(as<Map<MatrixXd> >(AA));
const int m(S.rows());
const MatrixXd SS(MatrixXd(m,m).setZero().
                  selfadjointView<Lower>().rankUpdate(S.adjoint()));
return wrap(SS);
"

library(inline)
fsq <- cxxfunction(signature(AA="matrix"), sqCpp,
                   plugin="RcppEigen")
ftri <- cxxfunction(signature(AA="matrix"), triCpp,
                   plugin="RcppEigen")

# Create symmetric matrix in R
library(Matrix)
x<-Matrix(rnorm(10000), 100)
# convert to normal matrix to pass to Rcpp
A <- as.matrix(forceSymmetric(x))

# Check to make sure same output
identical(fsq(A), ftri(A))
[1] TRUE

# Let's benchmark!!!
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(A%*%A, fsq(A), ftri(A))
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 A %*% A 1427.696 1465.6900 1546.9210 1491.217 1517.443 6442.999   100
  fsq(A)  296.617  315.8230  387.1591  342.957  355.039 5299.837   100
 ftri(A)  201.424  224.0515  247.9144  254.468  263.896  352.281   100
```

Comment: Eh, I had seen that in the intro, but it wasn't obvious to me that it would take advantage of the symmetry in S; my impression was the selfadjointView<Lower>() refers to the matrix of 0s being symmetric (from setZero()), right? (as the intro says, "read from left to right") - I don't see how RcppEigen knows that S is symmetric.

(edited to add: I can see that it works -- particularly by removing forceSymmetric and seeing that the results are not equal anymore -- but I don't see *why* the code works that way. As the intro says, "hopelessly confusing")

Comment: Actually, if one knew that S were symmetric here, why would it matter whether one uses S.adjoint() or S? The intro uses both in Figure 3, obviously because it needn't be symmetric...

Comment: @richarddmorey, I will try to explain more clearly.  You create a matrix will all zeros (`.setZero()`) which is then converted to symmetric using the lower triangle elements (`selfadjointView<Lower>()`).  Then you update those elements with the crossproduct (`rankUpdate(S.adjoint())`).  Finally, this matrix is converted to a general matrix again (where the lower elements are copied to the upper triangle).  You are also correct, that you don't necessarily need the transpose here.

Comment: @richarddmorey, also it is true that this assumes you know your matrix is symmetric.  You would need additional checks to determine otherwise if that is what you want.

Comment: OK, so the only use of the symmetry here is the knowledge that SS = S'S? I had assumed that there would be a fancy way of doing it via decompositions, but having experimented with eigen decompositions (noting that S = UDU' -> SS = UDU'UDU' -> UD^2U' for orthogonal eigenvector matrix U and diagonal eigenvector matrix D) but those are slower than your suggestion, so they don't fit the bill.